# Return day and month names in date/time function

Tags: javascript, date, time

I'm sure this question has been answered before, but I'd like to do this without including external JS libraries if possible, and that's all I've been able to find.

I need to generate date/time in the following format:

Wed, 10 Apr 2013 15:30:00

So far, this is my code, but it doesn't give me the month or day names as you see:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
document.write(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);
</script>
```

Comment: personally i would suggest using a library like: http://momentjs.com/ if you don't want to use a library look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795277/get-month-name-from-date-using-javascript-but-so-that-the-date-is-15-days-ahead?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Use the getDay and getMonth methods as indexes for arrays of the names you want to use-

```
var d = new Date();
var dayofweek=['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'][d.getDay()],
date = d.getDate(),
month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'][d.getMonth()],
year = d.getFullYear();

document.write([dayofweek,date,month,year,d.toLocaleTimeString()].join(' '));
```

/*  returned value: (String)
Thu 6 Jun 2013 12:44:36 PM
*/

Comment: How about skipping `date = d.getDate()` and just putting `d.getDate()` in the final expression? Also, not loving the `document.write`. :) Also, there are a few differences in your returned string when compared to the OPs requested format (24-hour time, comma after the day of week).

Answer (score 0):

To get Month you can write like this

```
var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"][d.getMonth()];
```

Comment: That's not the requested format. And OP does need weekdays as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [non-standard `toLocaleFormat` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat):

```
var d = new Date();
d.toLocaleFormat('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S');
```

This will return:

```
"Thu, 06 Jun 2013 15:58:35"
```

Comment: afaik this is only supported by FireFox, so - if we use the global market share of the browsers - for 80% it would not work.

Comment: Yes that is true. This is why @Barney should use a library.

Answer (score 0):

Following advice, it seems http://momentjs.com is the way to go. I downloaded it and had a fairly complex date/time in seconds :)

Much easier than messing around with the maths yourself. It's pretty lightweight too.